# Socket send() hangs when in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a C++ server application, written using the POCO framework. The server application is acting as a HTTP server in this case. There is a client application which I don't control and cannot debug that is causing a problem in the server. The client requests a large file, which is returned as the HTTP response. During the return of the file the client closes the connection. I see the socket move to the CLOSE_WAIT state, indicating that the client has sent a FIN. The trouble is that in my application the send() function then hangs causing one of my HTTP threads to be basically lost, and once all the threads enter this state the server is unresponsive.

The send code is inside the POCO framework, but looks like this:

```
    do
    {
            if (_sockfd == POCO_INVALID_SOCKET) throw InvalidSocketException();
            rc = ::send(_sockfd, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), length, flags);
    }
    while (_blocking && rc < 0 && lastError() == POCO_EINTR);
    if (rc < 0) error();
    return rc;
```

(flags are 0 in calls to this function). I tried to detect this state by adding the following code:

```
    char c;
    int r;
    int rc;
    do
    {
            // Check if FIN received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            while ((r = recv(_sockfd, &c, 1, MSG_DONTWAIT)) == 1) {}
            if (r == 0) { ::close(_sockfd); _sockfd = POCO_INVALID_SOCKET; } // FIN received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            if (_sockfd == POCO_INVALID_SOCKET) throw InvalidSocketException();

            rc = ::send(_sockfd, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), length, flags);
    }
    while (_blocking && rc < 0 && lastError() == POCO_EINTR);
    if (rc < 0) error();
    return rc;
```

This appears to make things better, but still not solve the problem. I end up with the server not hanging as quickly, but many more CLOSE_WAIT sockets, so I think I have partially solved the thread hanging issue, but I have still not tidied up correctly from the broken socket. With this change in place the problem happens less, but still happens, so I think the key to this is understanding why send() hangs.

I'm testing this code on linux.

Comment: Is there an actual question here, or is this merely a statement of a problem?

Comment: Do you want to block while you attempt to close the connection or not? It's not clear which you are attempting. It can take two minutes to tear down a TCP connection if the other side is uncooperative, so you probably don't want to block while it happens.

Comment: It hangs because you've filled up the socket send buffer and TCP is still trying to transmit/retransmit it to the peer. It looks like the client has shutdown and not closed the socket. There's not much point in looping while `recv()` returns 1. If it did, that's it, you haven't got a FIN yet, so proceed to the send.

Comment: I was trying to describe the problem clearly, but the question is how do I stop send() from hanging?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The CLOSE_WAIT socket appears to persist for a very long time, I have seen up to 24 hours before restarting the server, so it's not in the 2 minute timeout. 2 minutes would be better, but still probably not acceptable unless I increase the number of threads a lot.

Comment: @jdswain The sockets in CLOSE_WAIT are happening because of a bug in your code. Your code does not guarantee that you always call `close` before leaving the loop, nor does it guarantee that you don't try to access the socket after you call `close`. Fix those two trivial issues. Basically, you need to keep track of whether you closed the socket or not, otherwise how do you know if you're 100% done with or whether you need to keep doing stuff with it?

Comment: You'd probably be better off removing the receives and just suffering the two-minute block until ECONNRESET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cleanly close a socket:

1. Call `shutdown` with `SD_SEND`.
2. Keep reading from the socket until read returns zero or a fatal error.
3. Close the socket.
4. Do not attempt to access the socket after you've closed it.

Your code has two major issues. It doesn't ensure that `close` is always called on the socket no matter what happens, and it can access the socket after it has closed it. The former is causing your CLOSE_WAIT problem. The latter is a huge security hole.

Comment: Thanks David, this lead me to the solution (SD_SEND is a windows constant, but that was easy to change). My issue was that an exception was being thrown and the socket was not closed As soon as I caught the correct exceptions and called `shutdown` then `close` the issue was resolved. I still get CLOSE_WAIT sockets for a minute or two, but the code tidies up after itself now and doesn't hang like it did before.